# CakePHP Validation not working on password

Tags: php, cakephp

This seems to have popped up various times for others but I have seen no real explanation of the issue or what the fix is.

So basically I have some validation like:

```
var $validate = array(
    'password' => array( 
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'You must create a password'
    )
);
```

However:

1.) the validation message does not show?
2.) and on the postback the password field becomes filled with the validation rule???

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
var $validate = array(
    'password' => array( 
        'notEmpty' => array( 
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'You must create a password'
        )
    )
);
```

it uses the full validation array structure.

also you shoudnt use "password" as name. there are many tricks to avoid issues with this since in cake1.2 there is automatic going on which can cause strange things.
For example use pwd and set it to password on save.

tip: use a behavior for it:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/
this saves you a lot of trouble

Comment: "set it to password on save" can you explain how I would do this?

Comment: Also while we're on this subject could you show if I'm saving PWD as PASSWORD how I could have two password fields and make sure that they match. I presume if you're saving a field as another I will have to manually do the hashing?

Comment: you can make a new key in the save data array and pass the old one to it ...['password'] = ...['pwd']. look at my behavior (the link I gave you. there the matching password field rule is included. and no, the behavior would do that for you :)

Comment: the file is in github: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/models/behaviors/change_password.php

Comment: Hmm seems like a lot of work and for what seems like a bug in CakePHP!

Comment: its not a bug, as far as I can tell. 1.3 has some automagic than can interfere if not used accordingly, 2.0 doesnt have it anymore. does my array fix the strange error message issue?

Comment: No sorry the validation still does not appear for me :/

Comment: and did you try to move the form key to "pwd"? and in the model move it back to password on save. otherwise use my behavior - it works.

Comment: I don't want to use the behaviour! But could you show me how to do what you say so if I change the field name to pwd how would I save it as password???